# Mysqlimport and NULL values

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to load some pipe-delimited text files into tables using `mysqlimport` / `LOAD FROM INFILE`.

The files uses empty delimiters `||` for NULL values.

The result is a huge amount of warnings

> Warning 1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column

while importing.

I don't know if it's safe to ignore the warnings or not.

Doing a find-replace for `||` in the text file is kind of a last resort as their combined size is above 1GB. Any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can your column be null or not in your DB schema ?

If it can, it should be alright.

Comment: Yes, it can. I guess that's why it's a warning and not an error :)

Comment: So you can ignore the warnings. Just test for a few lines if it imports them or not, but I'm pretty sure you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Try to use mysql:> nowarning if you don't want to see them during importation : http://dionysus.uraganov.net/database/mysql/how-to-show-warnings-in-the-mysql-command-line-tool/

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will change `||` to `|0|` in no time :D 
 
well you can alter table:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY column int null;
```

and make that column accept null values.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @Antonio Glavocevic see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53584863/1050766

To correctly support nulls in the import, use `\N` instead of an empty value. Eg `foo|\N|123`